# Add Javascript function with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add an event trigger (onClick) with javascript dynamically.-at runtime.
I have a dynamic count of buttons, and on each button click, I need a specific javascript function.

I have the idea to add the javascript functions with javascript.

I tried that with some example:

```
document.getElementById("trigger").innerHTML = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">function testal() { alert(\"trigger\"); }<\/script>";
```

if i press on the button with the onClick="testal()":
Error Message: "is undefined"

Answer (score 0):

```
innerHTML is Not JavaScript.
```

[Indeed that causes a scription injection.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/134024/HTML-and-JavaScript-Injection)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("trigger").onclick = testal;
function testal() { alert('trigger'); }
```

In case you do not know beforehand what event you'd like to register the handler for (onclick, onkeydown, onkeypress etc) you can do:

```
var event_type = 'onclick';
document.getElementById('trigger')[event_type] = testal;
```

See also http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html

Comment: @Asad4k please don't use edits like this, if you think an answer need improving comment on it, or write an answer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [jquery .on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Try this

```
$(document).off('click', 'button');
$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
    alert('Executed');
});
```

If you do not know which event handler to be registered with button click, you can write your logic inside the anonymous handler.

Answer (score -2):

I solved it with

```
$("#trigger").html("<script type=\"text/javascript\">function testal() { alert(\"trigger\"); }<\/script>");
```